# Error get_posts with Custom Taxonomy and OR relation

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, get-posts, advanced-taxonomy-queries, tax-query

I've been stuck on this for hours... I did a `var_dump($list_items)` right before `if ( $list_items ) {` and it turns up empty, but a `var_dump($hold_tax_query)` looks (to me) like it should.

```
if($selected_custom_taxonomies){

$hold_tax_query = array('relation' => 'OR');

foreach ( $selected_custom_taxonomies as $a_tax ) :     
array_push($hold_tax_query, array('taxonomy' => 'customtax', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $a_tax->slug));
    endforeach; 

$list_items = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'custompost',
        'tax_query' => $hold_tax_query,
    )
);
//never gets past here because $list_items is empty...
if ( $list_items ) {

    foreach ( $list_items as $post ) :
        setup_postdata( $post ); 
?>
        <h2></h2>
        <?php the_field('description'); ?>
 <?php
    wp_reset_postdata();
endforeach; 
}
}
?>
```

Something is wrong with the array $hold_tax_query because when I only use 1 taxonomy field, it retrieves the custom post type...

**Update:**

Here is the output of the $hold_tax_query after the array_push loop and 3 tags were selected.

```
echo '<pre>' . var_export($hold_tax_query , true) . '</pre>';
```

The output:

```
array (
  'relation' => 'OR',
  0 => 
  array (
    'taxonomy' => 'listcat',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => 'mark',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'taxonomy' => 'listcat',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => 'school',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'taxonomy' => 'listcat',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => 'testeritem',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'taxonomy' => 'listcat',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => 'testtt',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$hold_tax_query` is an array of arrays? The correct format is `$hold_tax_query = array( array('taxonomy' => 'customtax', ...), array(...) )`

Comment: Sorry, it seems right. Just saw the initiation of `$hold_tax_query`

Comment: @Laxmana I'm assuming that's where the problem must lie... but I can't figure out what I did wrong

Comment: Could you craft the query yourself to see if it's working?

Comment: Another thing you can do is to `var_dump` the `global $wp_query` and see your query after `get_posts`

Comment: @Laxmana I added the output of $hold_tax_query to the OP. I also dumped $wp_query, but that is a lot of information...

Comment: @Laxmana Okay, the $wp_query has 'tax_query' => NULL, but its outputting right beforehand!

Comment: In this information there is your `$tax_query`. You can search and see if everything seems alright. (it can be empty for example). You can see also the how many posts the query returned etc. Btw the `$hold_tax_query` seems ok. Not sure what's the problem.

Comment: The global $wp_query will not contain the results of get_posts, if you want to inspect the query you need to use WP_Query.

Comment: @Milo Sorry I didn't know it. I assumed that because `get_posts` uses `WP_Query` that will be the case.